# При выборе checkbox изменить фон картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня картинки выводятся циклом + рядом с картинками выводится массив checkbox. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на checkbox, который относится к конкретной картинке, у картинки появился тёмный фон. Нужно это для того, чтобы пользователь визуально видел, какие картинки он хочет удалить, например.

```
<? foreach($rows as $k=>$img){ ?>
        <img src="<?= $img['name'] ?>" id="<?=$img[id]?>"  class="mg"  style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" >

        <input type="checkbox" id="mini" name="mini[]" value="<?=$img[id] ?>">

        <?}?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так. А дальше уже можно стилизовать под потребности.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid silver;
}
input:checked + label {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked id="img1"/>
<label for="img1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/180x180">
</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="img2"/>
<label for="img2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/180x180">
</label>
```

Comment: как я и сказал выше, картинки у меня выводятся циклом, как быть с <label for="_тут значение будет разное все время_">

Comment: так выводите не само изображение, а оберните его в лейбл в этом же цикле. а в `for="..."` генерируйте и подставляйте айдишку для вашего инпута.

Comment: спасибо помогло)